# Analytics view filtered for directory - what is a bounce?

Tags: google-analytics

We've been given access to a Google Analytics view filtered to include only traffic to a directory (/blog, say). I've been trying to find out:

1. What the referral information for visitors arriving in that directory from the rest of the site would be - would it be the referral information for when they got to the site itself?
2. When visitors leave that directory but remain on the site after viewing one page, would that be a bounce (in our view)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how the tracking is configed.

**Option A:** If the tracking code for the Analytics property is only added to pages within that section, then the answers would be:

1. The referrer would be the top level domain for the site.
2. Yes.

Because as far as that Analytics property is, that directory **is** the website and traffic from outside is not from the website.

**Option B:** If the tracking code is the same for the rest of the site, and the view is merely filtered to just show data for that directory:

1. The referrer would be the original referrer for that user session.
2. No.

This is because Analytics still sees the rest of the site, but it will only give you information for pageviews within that directory.

To be honest, option B possibly isn't the set up you want to work with as it doesn't help you if that directory is your sole concern. You might want to speak to the webmaster to have a new Analytics property set up for just that directory.

Comment: Really helpful answer, thank you! The main site has two GA tags on it, the directory we have GA access to only one, but it's one of those two so I guess your option B applies. Thanks again, much appreciated